# Finding variables in speech recognized text

Tags: java, grammar, speech, cmusphinx

I'm developing an application with speech recognition (Sphinx). From a config file I get all possible commands and build a JSGF grammar like this one:

```
<name> = ( Anna | Michael | somebody );
<command1> = Show me some information about <name>;
```

This works as it should and Sphinx recognizes e.g. "Show me some information about Anna". Great!
But now I have to find out that this recognition used command1 which belongs to sql query "SELECT information FROM people WHERE name=???". And I have to find the name in the recognized text to fill the ???.
Idea (but not very clever): When creating the grammar I store pairs of full command and full sql query like:

```
{
("Show me some information about Anna", "SELECT ... WHERE name='Anna'"),
("Show me some information about Michael", "SELECT ... WHERE name='Michael'"),
...
}
```

There must be a better way! Think about this advanced example:

```
<day> = ( first | second | ... );
<month> = ( January | February | ... );
<date> = the <day> of <month>
<command2> = Show me what <name> was doing on <date>;
```

So there are 2 variables to extract and there are nearly endless possibilities for the spoken date. It is not possible to build a List of all of them.

Hope you have more ideas than me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse speech output to a JSON to call Application API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253194/parse-speech-output-to-a-json-to-call-application-api)

Comment: You could use Rasa to do the NLP/U (natural language processing / understanding). It can be trained to detect intents like "showing information" and correlated entities like <name> or <date>.